# Force find stings just with digits inside and omit others

Tags: python, regex

What I have:

```
(1 lorem 2 ipsum: dolor. sit-amet:)
(consectetur adipiscing elit)
(JUST UPPER LETTERS)
(and lower letters)
(And Propper letters)
```

What I did:

`\([\d{1,} A-Za-z\.\-\:\;\,]{1,40}\)\b`

What I need:

A regex sentence to find just the first line (1 lorem 2 ipsum: dolor. sit-amet:) not the others. The special symbols can appers in any order as the digits, and any quantitie. I'm using Python

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please post expected output more clearly in your question, cheers.

Comment: Like this `\(\d[^()]+\)` or `\(\d[A-Za-z0-9.:;, -]{1,40}\)` https://regex101.com/r/pSKMNs/1 or `\([^\d()]*\d[^()]*\)` https://regex101.com/r/odj6Uo/1

Comment: Does it have to be regex? `[line for line in lines.splitlines() if any(c.isdigit() for c in line)]`

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a positive lookahead: `\((?=[^)]*\d)[^)]*\)` https://regex101.com/r/nWqE3d/1

Comment: Why are you looking at anything other than digits? Maybe your question title is misleading but it seems that you're only interested in strings that contain at least one digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start the match with the opening `(` followed by a digit, and then match 0-40 allowed characters after it before matching the closing `)`

You can omit the word boundary `\b` after the closing `)`

```
\(\d[A-Za-z0-9.:;, -]{0,40}\)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ARpWbL/1).

---

Or without the limit constraint, and matching at least a single digit between `(...)` using a negated character class:

```
\([^\d()]*\d[^()]*\)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(` Match `(`
- `[^\d()]*` Optionally match any char except for digits or `(` or `)`
- `\d` Match at least a single digit
- `[^()]*` Optionally match any char except for `(` or `)`
- `\)` Match `)`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FHb5nv/1).